# How can i Update My Product Export time consuming period for Bulk export products

Tags: export, varien, downloader, time, autoloader

In my store nearest 16,000 products are there, when i try to export both ways import/export or dataflow both are error. But when i export minimum of data i can able to export my products, which means i can't able to export all my products at a single file.

system - import/export - export error :

[image]

system - import/export - dataflow profiles - export all products error :

[image]

Comment: Increase `max_execution` time and `memory_limit` in your `php.ini` or `.htaccess`

Comment: Use this script it will use direct sql query for export it is much faster that magento exporter. https://github.com/megabait1212/magento-export/blob/master/export.php

Comment: Am increased but no use, could you pls suggest values, in my site 20,000 products

Comment: @AmanAlam : is this enough ??

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/lqcuJoK.png

Comment: As regard your github code, My export working,  Actually time out is my problem.

Comment: Yes php configration looks good now as problem resolved, I adding my first comment as answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42413/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-aman-alam).